# Combing URL component variables into a full URL

Tags: php

I would like to combine the variables below as a new variable called $fullurl.  They are components of a URL.  The structure of the combined variable is shown under the variables below.  How can I do this?

```
$urlc = nytimes.com/business/finance/articles/2005/05/10/20100727stock-prices-declining.html
$submissiondate = 2005-07-27 2022:38:10
$submittor = mike17
$countcomments = 15
$dispurl = nytimes.com
$submission = News about A Topic
$submissionid = 125
$domainurl = http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/index.php?
```

The combined order:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/index.php?submission=News+about+A+Topic++&submissionid=125&url=nytimes.com/business/finance/articles/2005/05/10/20100727stock-prices-declining.html&countcomments=15&submittor=mike17&submissiondate=2005-07-27%2022:38:10&dispurl=nytimes.com&subcheck=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it would be to put all of those into an array, and then use http_build_query.

So:

```
$params = array(
   'submittor' => 'mike17',
   'count_comments' => 15,
);

$query_string = http_build_query($params);

$fullurl = $domainurl . $query_string;
```

I left off some of your parameters for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array instead of separates variables, you can build the query string in this way:

```
$data = array(
          'foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
       );

$query_string = http_build_query($data);
```